# How to make a disk image file from a DVD on Windows that OSX can mount?

Tags: macos, iso-image, dmg-image

Question is pretty clear. Is there a software can do this or is there any other tricks?

I tried making an iso file with MagicISO Maker but in OSX i got "no mountable file systems" error.

Explanatory edit:
It is a game and I couldn't use mac's disk utility because my mac doesn't have a dvd rom.

But I solved it with a different approach; simply shared my dvd-rom from windows running laptop with LAN and used it from my mac.

Comment: Is the DVD a film? A game? Standard data? Encrypted in any way?

Comment: Why not use Macs Disk utility?